# CupertinoSliverRefreshControl with horizontal ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I have horizontal `ListView.builder` and `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl`, so when it reaches the end, I want to display Loading indicator, but for some reason I am getting error

> Null check operator used on a null value
> The relevant error-causing widget was
> CustomScrollView
> lib/sliver_loading.dart:19

The most unclear part is that `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` works fine with Vertical `ListView.builder`, but when I change Axis on horizontal it rises this above error.

Here is a code :

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, // Here is when Error rise
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  primary: false,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 4,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 200,
                      color: colors[index],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
              onRefresh: () async {
                await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
                print('loaded');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Can anyone explain me, why is this happening and what are the solutions?

Comment: Basically, the question is "how to use `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` with horizontal `ListView.builder`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is a way how I solved this problem. Since `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` does not work with horizontal `ListView.builder`, I decided to use `CupertinoActivityIndicator` and `CupertinoActivityIndicator.partiallyRevealed`.

When ListView reaches to the end, I am calculating distance between `ListView.builder()` and `int distance` and updating `double progress` for `CupertinoActivityIndicator.partiallyRevealed`, next when progress reaches `1.0` I just replace `CupertinoActivityIndicator.partiallyRevealed` with `CupertinoActivityIndicator` changing `bool isActive` value to `true`.

Finally it works like `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl`, just without slivers :).

Code Example

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HorizontalLoader extends StatefulWidget {
  const HorizontalLoader({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static final colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.indigoAccent,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.amberAccent,
    Colors.orange,
    Colors.purple,
    Colors.cyanAccent,
    Colors.red,
    Colors.indigoAccent,
    Colors.purple,
  ];

  @override
  State<HorizontalLoader> createState() => _HorizontalLoaderState();
}

class _HorizontalLoaderState extends State<HorizontalLoader> {
  int distance = 70; // offset
  bool isActive = false;
  double progress = 0.0;

  // Base logic. you can also use this logic with ScrollController()
  bool _handleNotification(ScrollNotification notify) {
    double outRangeLoading = distance + notify.metrics.maxScrollExtent;
    double currentPixel = notify.metrics.pixels;

    if (notify.metrics.extentAfter <= 0.0) {
      if (currentPixel >= outRangeLoading) {
        networkLoader();
      }

      calculateProgress(outRangeLoading, currentPixel);
    }
    return true;
  }

  // Some math
  void calculateProgress(outRangeLoading, currentPixel) {
    double current, currentAsPrecent;

    current = outRangeLoading - currentPixel;
    currentAsPrecent = (100 * current) / distance;

    setState(() {
      progress = (100 - currentAsPrecent) * 0.01;
    });
  }

  // To simulate loading data from Network
  void networkLoader() async {
    isActive = true;
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
    isActive = false;
    setState(() {
      progress = 0.0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200, bottom: 200),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              right: 15,
              top: 210,
              child: isActive
                  ? CupertinoActivityIndicator()
                  : CupertinoActivityIndicator.partiallyRevealed(
                      progress: progress,
                    ),
            ),
            NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
              onNotification: _handleNotification,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: HorizontalLoader.colors.length + 1,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  if (index == HorizontalLoader.colors.length) {
                    return isActive ? SizedBox(width: 50) : SizedBox();
                  }
                  return Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: HorizontalLoader.colors[index],
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: CupertinoSliverRefreshControll with horizontal ListView]

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround with current snippet instead of using `CupertinoSliverRefreshControl` return row with loading widget for last item. Also wrap `Container` with `Center`.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
  return index == 13 // items length-1
      ? Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              width: 100,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.cyanAccent,
            ),
            CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ],
        )
      :Center( child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          width: 100,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.amber,
        ));
},
```

If you do use ListView, you can use `ScrollController` with listener and get position to load data using `controller.position.maxScrollExtent* .9` ;load more on 90% scroll.

Also, using the same directional multi-scrollabe widgets is not necessary. We can skip using `ListView` and use `SliverList`. While the width is fixed, we can compare the items' length and current scroll position to using the controller.

```dart
 final ScrollController controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller.addListener(() {
      print(controller.offset);
      //14 total item , I am using 90%
      if (controller.offset > 100 * 14 * .9) {
        // you may encounter multiple call use another flag or null to handle this
        print("load more");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: controller,
          slivers: [
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => index == 13 // items length-1
                    ? Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                            width: 100,
                            height: 200,
                            color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                          ),
                          CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ],
                      )
                    : Center(
                        child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                        width: 100,
                        height: 200,
                        color: Colors.amber,
                      )),
                childCount: 14,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```